# Return unique set of numbers from a list

Tags: algorithm

Given two numbers m and n, m smaller than n, return a set of m random unique numbers from 1 to n. For example, this is the same as giving random lottery numbers if you had m = 6 and n = 49.

One way of doing this is use a random number generator to get number between 0 and 1,  multiply by n, truncate to integer, check if number is already in set, if not add to set, repeat until we have m numbers.

Another way is firstly create an array with the numbers 1 to n, randomly reorder the numbers, read off the first m numbers.

I think the first is better if m is small compared to n, for example if m = 1 and n = 1000000 the first will be clearly much quicker. However if m is large I think the second method would be better, for example if m = 500000 and n = 1000000 the first method would probably have to repeat itself a lot of times if you keep getting numbers returned that have already been added to the set.

My question is, is there a mathematical way of working out the relationship between m and n for when it becomes more efficient to use one method over the other?

Comment: And what is your method to "randomly reorder the numbers"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about probability analysis. [math.se] *might* be more appropriate for some derived version of this question.

Comment: @PaulDraper Probably referring to built-in functions in some languages like shuffle().

Comment: One hint is that if m <= n/2, then for the last element you have a probability of at most 1/2 of it already being in the list. Clearly the probabilities of the previous numbers being in the set are less than 1/2. If we take 1/2 as an upper bound, then, on average, you're going to draw 2 * m = n numbers, which is the same as the second option. If m > n/2 I would go with the second option.

Comment: If m is over n/2 you can of course use the first method but take the numbers which do not appear in your set. For example if m = 90 and n = 100, use the method to get 10 numbers and then your 90 numbers are all the others. The first method is at its least efficient then when m = n/2.

Comment: Side note - you don't have to reorder **the whole** array. With [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm), you can just stop when you have m elements.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, and some languages might have a built-in function to return a random combination. But since this asks about algorithms, it is important to know what the *algorithm* is.

Comment: @user2802557 You could take the complement, but you still need to do a second pass to remove from 1..n what you selected, so I don't think it's better. That said, they are both O(n) in that case, so it won't matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment. Let E[X_i] be the expected number of draws before we pick an element not already in the set. If the probability to pick something not in the set is `p`, then we have

```
E[X_i] = 1/p
```

To see this, think that either we pick correctly (with probability p), or we don't in which case we have added a draw, hence

```
E[X_i] = p + (1 - p) * (1 + E[X_i])
```

from which `E[X_i] = 1/p`.

Now for the i-th element (starting from 0), `p = (n - i) / n`, hence `E[X_i] = n / (n - i)`. Summing over all `E[X_i]` with `i < m` we get the expected number of draws to extract `m` numbers. For `m <= n/2`, this is clearly better than creating a list of `n` elements and shuffling it.

Comment: How do you get to your conclusion on the last line that this is clearly better than creating the list and shuffling it?

Comment: Well, the last element to be picked has E[X_i] = n / (n - n/2) = 2. This is larger than n / (n - i) for i < n / 2, so the sum is bounded above by (n / 2) * 2 = n. You need at least n operations to shuffle.

Comment: You will actually only need m operations for the shuffle as you can stop once you have the first m numbers, there is no need to shuffle the rest. Therefore if m = n/2 could this be quicker?

Comment: Good point. I don't think you can do that with Fisher Yates, though. For that you need to build the array 1..n which is O(n) in itself. Would love to know if its possible, though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you were starting with an array [1,2,...,n], you could repeatedly swap the i'th element with the element in a position chosen at random from i to n. Do this for 1 <= i <= m, and you're done.

Making the array is inefficient if m << n. You can duplicate this behavior without the array by making a map from integers to integers. Proceed as above, but instead of reading from the i'th position of the array, check to see if i is a key of your map, and pull the value stored. Similarly, where you would put an element into the i'th position, instead store it in your map as the value associated with the key i.

This is O(m).

Answer (score 1):

We measure an algorithm by it's [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), which expresses how fast the time cost increases with the increasing of the input size.

In your case, your first algorithm won't work. Generating a random number until it doesn't equal to a given number has a chance to take infinite time. So let's improve it a little bit by:

1. make a list with all the N candidate numbers;
2. generate a random number R from 1 and N;
3. select the R-th number from the list;
4. remove the selected number from the list; let N be N-1;
5. go to step 2, until get M selected numbers.

This improved algorithm has an upper bound of time complexity. The complexity of step 3~4 is O(M), no matter using linear or linked list. They would be repeated M times. The overall complexity of this algorithm is **`O(NM)`**.

The complexity of your second algorithm is **`O(N)`** using the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

So, **the second algorithm is the winner on complexity.** Please note that it just means that the winner's time cost *increases slower* when the input size increases. It doesn't mean that it *always take less time* than another one. **We don't measure an algorithm by its absolute time cost,** because it varies with different hardwares, systems, languages and compilers etc. **We take time complexity instead.**

Comment: Shuffling can be done in linear time using [Fisher Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: I think this improved algorithm you have come up with is another way of saying the second method. Creating a list of all the possible elements then choosing them out at random is the same as just rearranging the list. I don't think you can just say the second method is faster than the first, if m = 2 and n = 1000 even though it is possible the first method could take infinite time it would almost always be much faster than the second method

Comment: I wouldn't really call your 'improvement' an improvement. The best case of the original is O(M).

Comment: @user2802557 Complexity is used to measure **how fast the time cost increases when the input size increases**, not to measure **how much is the time cost with a given input**.

Comment: Actually it can be. [Just about any algorithm on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) lists best / worst / average case complexity.

Comment: @Dukeling In the original one, to check `if a number has been selected` takes O(N). Repeated M times.

Comment: Generate random number - `O(1)`, check if it's in the (hash)set - `O(1)`, repeat until you find one that's not in the set. Not sure how you got `O(N)`.

Comment: @Dukeling You are right. Thank you. I forgot the hash. Let me do the math for their average complexity.

Comment: @Dukeling the mean of times to select the i-th number is `N/(N-i+1)` (it's geometrically distributed), so to select M numbers take `Sum(N/(N-i+1)) (i from 1 to M)`. This Taylor series exactly equals to `NM`. So the average complexity of these two are the same `O(NM)`. And due to the original one could be infinite at worst case, so I would argue that mine is better.

Comment: If M = 1, then it only takes O(1), not O(N.1), so I'm not convinced your analysis is correct. For M << N, the first approach would definitely be better. (But [Dave's variation on the second approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20722178/1711796) appears to be the clear winner at consistently expected O(M)).

Comment: if M = 1, the total times of generating is `Sum(N/(N-i+1)) (i from 1 to M) = Sum(N/(N-1+1)) (i from 1 to 1) = 1`, what's wrong with my analysis? It's `O(NM)` on *average*, not on M=1 :)